# How to solve linear equations using solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, math, auctions

I am setting up a contract which gets initialized with the following parameters:

```
startDate, endDate, startPrice
```

The price at any given points is the line connecting the two points `a` and `b` where

`a*endDate + b =0`

`a*startDate + b = startPrice`

These two equations need to be solved inorder to get the price at any time `x` which will be `a*x+b`

What would be the suggested methods to solve the linear  equations here?

Comment: have you search for a way to solve an algorithm to solve a linear equation there are a lot online already

Comment: @haxerl did search for that, but couldn't find anything that could be used in solidity